# Can't change the default filesystem disk in Laravel because the settings in filesystem.php being ignored

Tags: laravel, config

I want to change the default filesystem disk in Laravel 5.8 from "local" to "public". Unfortunately the changes in **filesystems.php** and **.ENV** are not taken into account. 
The only way I was able to change the default filesystem disk was to change the **config.php** file.

I added this line in **.ENV**:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

Alwso in **filesystems.php** I changed:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local')
```

to

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public')
```

I restarted the server after the changes, but still none of the above solutions worked for me. The only way to change the default filesystem disk was to make changes directly in the **config.php** file.

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` then try

Comment: or `php artisan config:clear` and `route:clear`

Comment: I know of the `config` directory but `config.php` in Laravel 5.8?... Where is such file located?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya in `bootstrap/cache/config.php` but `php artisan config:cache` should refresh the needed config settings.

Comment: @S.Asenov did you edit the .env on the production server? If you use version control, this file is (and **should be**) ignored. You have to manually edit the file on production and run the config:cache. Restarting the server is not needed.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey He is not supposed to edit `bootstrap/cache/config.php`. He should make his changes in `config/filesystems.php`, then run `php artisan config:cache` and let's see how that goes.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya He means manually editing the `.env` file.

Comment: Exaclty @ceejayoz I just pointed out where the file is located but it shouldn't be changed as it is automatically created by either `config:cache` or `composer update`. As a side note, on production, the .env file is, apart from these 2 commands, completely ignored for security reasons.

Comment: @Hamelraj,  
Thank you so much. 
`php artisan config:clear` did work.

Comment: @S.Asenov in production you should run `php artisan config:cache` to make sure the `config.php` is populated with your settings. You'll notice this command runs config:clear anyway. You will find the same command in the `composer.json` file in the `post-update-cmd` section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution has been pointed out in the comments under my question. 
For changes to take effect, you need to clear the configuration cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```